# How to handle a bad CSV file import in Symfony/PHP

Tags: php, csv, symfony, truncate

I am uploading **a lot of data** from a csv without problem but *I would like to protect a possible user error*, in the sense that it is possible that they put a bad csv in the form ...

The problem is that I truncate my table every time the form is launched ...

```php
ImportController.php

       $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
       ->add('form', FileType::class, [
           'attr' => ['accept' => '.csv',
           'class' => 'custom-file-input'],
           'label' => 'Import'
       ])
       ->getForm();
       
       $form->handleRequest($request);

           if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
           {
               /** 
                * @var UploadedFile
                */
               $file = $form->get('form')->getData();  
               $connection = $em->getConnection();
               $platform = $connection->getDatabasePlatform();
               $connection->beginTransaction();
               $connection->executeQuery($platform->getTruncateTableSQL('MyTable', true));
               $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(MyTable::class)->importMyData($file);           
       
               $this->addFlash('success',"The csv has been successfully imported");
               return $this->redirectToRoute('import');
           }
```

```php
MyTableRepository.php

public function importMyData($file)
    {
        $em = $this->entityManager;

        if (($handle = fopen($file->getPathname(), "r")) !== false) 
        {
            $count = 0;
            $batchSize = 1000;
            $data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ","); 

            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== false) 
            {
                $count++;
                $entity = new MyTable();

                // 40 entity fields...
                $entity->setFieldOne($data[0]);                
                $entity->setFieldTwo($data[1]); 
                //....
                $entity->setFieldForty($data[39]); 

                $em->persist($entity);

                if (($count % $batchSize) === 0 )
                {
                    $em->flush();
                    $em->clear();
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
            $em->flush();
            $em->clear();
        }
    }
```

**I just want that when a bad CSV file is launched that the table is not Truncate**

Comment: Do you know how to detect a bad file?

Comment: hum I guess not, but it's not the file itself the problem, it's the content.

Comment: Well, when you develop a method of determining that a file is bad, the check becomes a trivial `if` condition.

Comment: But then at what level should I check this? to avoid the truncate? During the form ?

Comment: why not wrap the call to your "importMyData" function in a try/catch/finally block and rollback the database transaction on an exception? You can throw an exception inside importMyData if fgetcsv returns an error or if the data it reads doesn't pass whatever validation criteria you have.

Comment: @couteau I tried something like this, with rollBack (), but maybe I was wrong, I'll try again thanks.

Comment: The most natural place would be the form submission code. Take the uploaded file, test it and then don't run the transaction if it's bad and return a response with an error for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sanitize and validate data before insert into the database. You can attempt this many ways. First I would use Symfony file validator to make sure to check valid file has been uploaded.

[Symfony File Validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#mimetypes)

To validate each row you can use custom callback validator or raw values of the array
[Validate Raw Data](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html)

```
//call the validator in the repository
$validator = Validation::createValidator();

// sample input
$input = [
'field_1' => 'hello',
'field_2' => 'test@email.tld',
'field_40' => 3
];

//define the constraints for each row
$constraint = new Assert\Collection([
// the keys correspond to the keys in the input array
'field_1' => new Assert\Collection([
    'first_name' => new Assert\Length(['min' => 101]),
    'last_name' => new Assert\Length(['min' => 1]),
]),
'field_2' => new Assert\Email(),
'field_40' => new Assert\Length(['min' => 102])
]);

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== false) {
  $violations = $validator->validate($data, $constraint);
  
  // you can skip the row or log the error
  if ($violations->count() > 0) {
    continue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you, *I'm stupid*, I just put a "try catch" which returns something else if an error occurs in the importMyData function, then I check in my Controller if this value is returned ... If so, I redirect etc.